# Problemas Con INNER JOIN PONER UN CASE WHEN cuandoes un CONCAT

Tags: sql

No logro redondear , lo que necesito es que tengo un `left join` de la cual el `ON` es de dos `concat`

```
LEFT JOIN BD_MigracionQV.dbo.TBL_QV_Hecho_Produccion_IF Produccion 
  ON CONCAT(Cita.IdPaciente, Cita.IdMedico,
 convert(char(10), Cita.FechaCita,101))=CONCAT(Produccion.IdPaciente,Produccion.IdMedicoAtencion,convert(char(10),Produccion.Fecha,101))
```

lo que pasa es que en esta parte se unes la dos tablas que uno ahí esta bien pero el problema es la fecha que cambia En el primer `CONCAT` esta bien pero en el segundo varia en la fecha como comente,El `concat` puede ser uno así

```
CONCAT(Produccion.IdPaciente,Produccion.IdMedicoAtencion,convert(char(10),
Produccion.Fecha,101)) o CONCAT(Produccion.IdPaciente,Produccion.IdMedicoAtencion,
convert(char(10),Produccion.FechaInicioOa,101))
```

Comment: Ese código es sql, por qué usaste la etiqueta de jquery?

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Porque haces un concat de los tres campos y no unis en el join por los 3 campos que es mucho mas simple? o sea.. no deberias usar concat como clausula de join.. nunca...

Comment: Christian, bienvenido a StackOverflow... En mi opinión, tener que usar `CONCAT` como criterio de un `JOIN` es un indicativo de que algo anda mal en tu diseño de datos. ¿Puedes justificar por qué recurres a esa extraña práctica?

Comment: Si lo que pasa es que tengo dos bases de datos una de que es citas y otra la cual es consultas,

Comment: yo recurro a la concatenacion ya que las dos tablasque estan en distintas bases de datos la unica similitud es el idpacient, idmedico y bueno la fecha;

Comment: luego cuando veo que me falta datos y el porque es por que la fecha de cita con la fecha que tiene mi consulta son distintos

Comment: y veo que cuando no son iguales no lo cuenta o no se unen y cuando si si los une, pense hacer un case when indicando si son iguales  CONCAT(Cita.IdPaciente, Cita.IdMedico,
 convert(char(10), Cita.FechaCita,101))=CONCAT(Produccion.IdPaciente,Produccion.IdMedicoAtencion,convert(char(10),Produccion.Fecha,101)) y si no CONCAT(Cita.IdPaciente, Cita.IdMedico,
 convert(char(10), Cita.FechaCita,101))=CONCAT(Produccion.IdPaciente,Produccion.IdMedicoAtencion,convert(char(10),Produccion.FechaOA,101))

Comment: es por eso a que recurro a la concatenacion

Comment: Al leer tus comentarios, se puede llegar a la conclusión de que no has entendido realmente lo que es un sistema de bases de datos relacional en el cual las tablas se relacionan entre sí por columnas que las identifican. Supongamos una relación entre tres tablas: `pais, provincia, ciudad`. Para indicar que la ciudad `X` pertenece a la provincia `Y`, habrá en la tabla `ciudad` una columna `id_provincia`; para indicar que la provincia `A` pertenece al país `B`, habrá en la tabla `provincia` una columna `id_pais`. En la consulta no habría que usar `CONCAT` para los `JOIN` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lamentablemente no comprendo del todo la pregunta y en verdad creo que falta más información o falta que apliques tu solución de otra manera.

¿Por qué necesitas una unión tan compleja entre dos tablas utilizando concatenaciones? Tal vez lo que buscas se realiza más por un where que por la unión en sí.

Puedes unir las columnas por separado así:

```
left join tabla2 tbl2 on tbl1.idMedico=tbl2.idMedico and tbl1.idPaciente=tbl2.idPaciente
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83743/discussion-on-answer-by-koken-problemas-con-inner-join-poner-un-case-when-cuando).

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys , debido a mi baja reputación no podía iniciar un chat.

Comment: Se que no puedes pero cuando el sistema detecta cierta cantidad de comentarios te lo sugiere y puedes entrar, esto aún y que no puedas crear chat @Koken Recuerda que para obtener reputación hay que crear preguntas basadas en [ask] y respuestas basadas en [answer], incluso puedes obtener reputación ayudando con la moderación del sitio, editando, sugiriendo mejoras, incluso ayudando en las colas de revisión. Por lo pronto ya puedes comentar e ingresar a un chat https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat.